# Using variables in fancybox config

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have set up this configuration inside my html, but I keep getting an error (Unexpected identifier). Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        closeBtn  : false,

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            },
            buttons : {}
        },

        afterLoad : function() {
            this.title = (this.index + 1) + '. ' + longNames[this.index];
        }

        error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">'+fnbx_err+'</p>',
        closeBtn : '<a title="'+fnbx_clo+'" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
        next     : '<a title="'+fnbx_nex+'" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
        prev     : '<a title="'+fnbx_pre+'" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not because of the variables. You forgot to put the last part inside `tpl`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        closeBtn  : false,

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            },
            buttons : {}
        },

        afterLoad : function() {
            this.title = (this.index + 1) + '. ' + longNames[this.index];
        },

        tpl : {
            error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">'+fnbx_err+'</p>',
            closeBtn : '<a title="'+fnbx_clo+'" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
            next     : '<a title="'+fnbx_nex+'" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
            prev     : '<a title="'+fnbx_pre+'" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
        }
    });
});
```